# Systemd not getting pid 1 when in docker container

Tags: debian, systemd, docker

I am trying to bring up continuous integration pipeline and that requires me to apt install an abc.deb file inside container.

The debian/control file do include:

```
Depends:  ${python3:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, python3-webpy, systemd
```

The debian/rules file include(only relevant part showcased below):

```
%:
dh $@  --with=python3,systemd

override_dh_systemd_start:
    dh_systemd_start -p<application>

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_systemd_start
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM <relevant base image>
COPY results/*.deb /packages/
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --auto-remove \
    dumb-init \
    procps \
    /packages/*.deb && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/apt
    CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

When I docker exec inside the docker and do ps aux, I get:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2388   756 ?        Ss   11:51   0:00 /bin/sh -c tail -f /dev/null
```

How can I have systemd as PID 1 ? ever per say dumb-init!

I tried looking to multiple articles, appears that it isn't possible, requires confirmation on same. The good ones are (to name few):

https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/

https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to run inside the container?  It's generally best practice to run a single process (or a small set of closely-related processes) so something like `systemd` is often not needed.

Comment: The title and the tail end of your question talk about PID 1 & systemd, but the first 80% of your question goes on to talk about installing a particular package. Is your question about some trouble with the package installation? If not, consider removing that portion from the question. As-is, you've demonstrated that your dockerfile has the intended result -- the "CMD" is running.

Comment: Most Docker images are designed for a single process, so there is no need for a process manager.  There are `systemd` Docker base images, have you tried using one of those?  Running `systemd` inside Docker usually needs some additional configurations such as sharing the host's CGroups and making sure the required `tmpfs` filesystems are available (`/run` and `/tmp` IIRC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [GracefulRestart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/281407/gracefulrestart) mentioned in the comment, you can build from systemd base image. For example, [centos-systemd](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/). But it's definitely not recommended to use systemd inside a docker container. Take a look at my [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452249/docker-container-with-centos-7-and-systemd).

If you need systemd only to meet dependencies, the better way is to [ignore deb dependency](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies/859394).